# Get text from script output

Tags: php, output, file-get-contents

everyone, I've been using this code for quite a long time

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.smn.gov.ar/mensajes/index.php?observacion=metar&operacion=consultar&87582=on&87641=on&87750=on&87765=on&87222=on&87761=on&87860=on&87395=on&87344=on&87166=on&87904=on&87571=on&87347=on&87803=on&87576=on&87162=on&87532=on&87497=on&87097=on&87046=on&87548=on&87217=on&87506=on&87692=on&87418=on&87574=on&87715=on&87374=on&87289=on&87852=on&87178=on&87896=on&87823=on&87270=on&87155=on&87453=on&87925=on&87934=on&87480=on&87047=on&87553=on&87311=on&87909=on&87436=on&87509=on&87912=on&87623=on&87444=on&87129=on&87371=on&87645=on&87022=on&87127=on&87828=on&87121=on&87938=on&87791=on&87448=on';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// search for td's containing METAR
$metars = $xpath->query('//td[contains(text(), "METAR SA")]');
if($metars->length <= 0) {
echo 'no metars found';
exit;
}

$data = array();
foreach($metars as $metar) {
$data[] = $metar->nodeValue;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Well, this was working fine, until the program in charge to read the output was updated and now it needs a clear output.

At the momment I'm getting this:
http://ar.ivao.aero/weather/metar.php
But the program needs it like this:

```
SABE 161600Z 02006KT 9999 FEW030 24/18 Q1009 =
SAZA 161600Z 18011KT CAVOK 24/08 Q1010 =
SAZB 161700Z 27012KT CAVOK 21/09 Q1011 =
```

I don't thought maybe using another script like a file_get_content() could be useful but again its going to show the infromation I don't want to.
I also tried replacing print_r() by var_dump() but its the same

Any ideas?
There is anyway to get this informatin in a simple txt file?

Regards,

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code. I just copy and pasted what you provided and ran it locally. No problems and it only returned the records with METAR SA.

Comment: Yeah, but its returning the records with `Array
(
    [0] =>` in the front, and the new program doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out some data. Try to find out what's common in the info you need to output. For instance, all the required info from your raw `print_r` data seems to beging with METAR. So

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($metars as $metar) {
    if(substr($metar->nodeValue, 0, 5) === "METAR") {
         echo str_replace("METAR ", "", $metar->nodeValue) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

That removes any lines like `Aeropuerto FORMOSA` from the output.

Comment: I tried it and thr result is `Array ()` anyways the program doesn't allow the `Array ( [0] =>` at the beginning

Comment: My bad, I was missing a `->nodeValue` inside the condition. As for the beginning `Array()`, the `print_r` function will do that, you shouldn't use it. No need for it anymore since I added an `echo` straight from the loop.

Comment: Thanks, any idea about how I could do the same without `print_r()`?

Comment: Yes, see my updated code. I use an `echo` straight from the loop and added an end-of-line character.